# io.github.jan.supabase.exceptions.BadRequestRestException: Error (headers must have required property 'authorization') from supabase-kt

Tags: java, android, kotlin, supabase

I'm creating a Kotlin application on Android Studio with Supabase integration via the [`io.github.jan-tennert.supabase` dependencies](https://github.com/supabase-community/supabase-kt), but
I'm running into the following error when trying to use the `Storage.BucketApi.upload()` method in the `io.github.jan-tennert.supabase:storage-kt:1.0.0` library:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.coding.informer.dictionary_app_v3, PID: 23547
io.github.jan.supabase.exceptions.BadRequestRestException: Error (headers must have required property 'authorization')
URL: https://juessugxmpdtjuexmdwj.supabase.co/storage/v1/object/bookmarked_words/
Headers: [x-upsert=[false], apikey=[<Removed for security reasons>], Accept=[application/json], Accept-Charset=[UTF-8]]
Http Method: POST
 at io.github.jan.supabase.storage.StorageImpl.parseErrorResponse(Storage.kt:271)
 at io.github.jan.supabase.gotrue.AuthenticatedSupabaseApiKt$authenticatedSupabaseApi$3.invoke(AuthenticatedSupabaseApi.kt:62)
 at io.github.jan.supabase.gotrue.AuthenticatedSupabaseApiKt$authenticatedSupabaseApi$3.invoke(AuthenticatedSupabaseApi.kt:62)
 at io.github.jan.supabase.network.SupabaseApi.rawRequest$suspendImpl(SupabaseApi.kt:25)
 at io.github.jan.supabase.network.SupabaseApi$rawRequest$1.invokeSuspend(Unknown Source:15)
 at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoop.processUnconfinedEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:68)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuation.resumeWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:345)
 at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.resumeRootWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:135)
 at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:109)
 at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun.access$loop(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:11)
 at io.ktor.util.pipeline.SuspendFunctionGun$continuation$1.resumeWith(SuspendFunctionGun.kt:59)
 at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:46)
 at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
 Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@b6b5375, Dispatchers.Main.immediate]
```

I can see that the `Authorization=Bearer ...` header is missing in the above request, which is mostly likely the root cause behind this error.

**Background Info:**

I have instantiated a `SupabaseClient` instance via:

```
val client = createSupabaseClient(
      supabaseUrl = BuildConfig.supabase_project_url,
      supabaseKey = BuildConfig.supabase_project_api_key,

  ) {
      install(Storage) {

      }
  }
```

And using `storage.get(bucketId = '')` works as expected:

```
val bookmarked_works_bucket : BucketApi = client.storage.get(bucketId = "bookmarked-words")
```

It is only when I try to upload an object to the Supabase Bucket via the following line that I'm running into the aforementioned error:

```
bookmarked_works_bucket.upload("words", "sampleWord".toByteArray())
```

Note that I have already found the solution to this error, which I will post as an answer in case it helps others running into the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the `supabase-kt` library will use the API key as authentication and add the `Authorization=Bearer ...` header to the API request only if the `GoTrue` plugin is installed.

Adding the `GoTrue` plugin resolved this error.

I added the `GoTrue` plugin by adding the following lines to my module level `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation platform('io.github.jan-tennert.supabase:bom:1.0.0')
implementation 'io.github.jan-tennert.supabase:gotrue-kt:1.0.0'
```

And then by adding it to `createSupabaseClient()` like so:

```
val client = createSupabaseClient(
    supabaseUrl = BuildConfig.supabase_project_url,
    supabaseKey = BuildConfig.supabase_project_api_key,
) {
    install(Storage) {

    }
    install(GoTrue) {

    }
}
```

Side note: after making the above changes I still got a `Invalid JWT - new row violates row-level security policy for table "objects"` error, but I was able to fix that by adding a new policy on the Supabase dashboard(SQL expression for it: `(bucket_id = 'insert-bucket-name'::text)`)